# Upgrade to 10.3 resulted in deleting configuration from old version

Tags: mariadb, auto-increment

We've recently upgraded MariaDB from 10.1 to 10.3 from Cpanel.

After the upgrade we started to having issues in the INSERT clauses where we use

**INSERT into table values ('','one')**

where the first column is an column with integer and auto-increment.

We are getting this error:

**"Incorrect integer value: ''"**

---

Issuing the query:

**"SELECT @@SQL_MODE, @@GLOBAL.SQL_MODE;"**

Results in:

@@SQL_MODE: NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

@@GLOBAL.SQL_MODE: NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

---

When NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO is there, newly inserted ID's do not respect the auto_increment property and the last value is 0

Can you shed some light on what configuration must be made in order to make INSERT's use empty values in auto-increment columns?

Removing NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO is one action.

Thank you in advance

Comment: did you run the upgrade coamnd see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/upgrading/ and you must first go from 10.1. to 10.2 and so on but follow the instrictions

Comment: I believe so. Since it was automated from cpanel.

Comment: no, i believe that it was correct updated, as you need first tpo upgrade from 10 .1 to 19,2 but read the link and do the steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @nbk, we've set global sql mode to the default values from 10.1

NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION